# Problems with Normal.dot

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Microsoft Office word keep asking if I want to replace the normal.dot file? Can I fix this?](https://superuser.com/questions/170983/why-does-microsoft-office-word-keep-asking-if-i-want-to-replace-the-normal-dot-fi)

What is Normal.dot?

How can I get MS Word (2003) to stop asking to overwrite it?

Why does Word do so in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Normal.dot` is the default or global template that Word uses to create a blank document. `Normal.dot` is always in use when Word is open, even if you are using another template. .

---

> Some Facts About Normal.dot
>
> - When you launch Word, it looks for normal.dot and opens it.
> - If your normal.dot is corrupt, it can cause Word to crash upon launching.
> - If Word cannot locate a normal.dot file, it creates a brand new one.

More details on [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291352)

Comment: Bad User! Bad User! How could you miss the duplicate! :)

Comment: O_0 dang! I have no idea how I missed the dupe 0_o @Diago